# TFS CI build - NuGet.exe failed with return code: 1

Tags: tfs, build, continuous-integration, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I'm in the process of using [this walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4?tabs=vsts) to configure TFS to automatically build my applications upon check-in.

When I Save and Queue the build, it successfully completes the "Initalize Job" and "Get Sources" step. During the "NuGet Restore" step, it skips several solutions saying:

```
All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
```

(which I'm assuming is fine) and then fails on one specific solution, saying:

```
Error: C:\agent\_work\_tasks\NuGetInstaller_333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f23b\0.2.31\node_modules\nuget-task-common\NuGet\4.0.0\NuGet.exe failed with return code: 1
Packages failed to install
```

After Googling around, the general consensus seems to be that NuGet 3.3 has issues with these automated builds and I need to set the NuGet version to 3.5 in the Build Definition. I tried that and I get the same error.

If it's helpful, the only NuGet package installed on the solution is [AjaxControlToolkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AjaxControlToolkit/) version 17.1.0 (it was originally version 7-something before I updated it hoping to solve my issue).

**What does this error indicate?**

Per the request from the comments, here are the contents of the packages.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
    <package id="AjaxControlToolkit" version="17.1.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
</packages>
```

Comment: The error is hiding the real problem, try this https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/2747 - failing that run the command manually, eg `C:\agentWeb\_work\_tasks\NuGetInstaller_333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f23b\0.2.31\node_modules\nuget-task-common\NuGet\3.3.0\NuGet.exe restore -NonInteractive C:\agentWeb\_work\5\s\Web.API.sln` and see if that yields any clues, if it doesn't  try run ProcessMonitor when you manually run the command to see if there's any errors with the files its touching.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with a new project? Try to set system.debug variable to true, then queue build and check whether there is detail error.

Comment: @JeremyThompson - I disabled the NuGet Restore step and checked the Restore NuGet Packages box as you link recommends. I now get `Error MSB5010: No file format header found.`

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with the new project and new build definition?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT - No, I can't. Part of the tutorial linked above has you download a sample solution and I'm able to build with that solution with no problems. But when I set it up to use my own code, I get the errors.

Comment: What's the detail code of packages.config? That're steps you set it up to use your own code? Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive? (Set system.debug variable to true, then queue build and share the log)

Comment: @ThelronCheek, what were the results of manually running the command? And did ProcMon show any clues? I've run into this before. The new error is a MS Build file error, if I were you create a fresh new CI build, if that doesn't work at least now you have a working (downloaded sample) vs non-working solutions to use your fav Diff tool...

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issue, and you're right, this is an issue with NuGet version 3.3.0.  You can simply switch the version by going to the TFS Nuget Restore build step, expand the "Advanced" section, then click on "3.5.0".  I also changed the Verbosity to "Detailed".